# How to get Countrycode value from only receive callnumber in android?

Tags: android

When i pass number(+972573481112") and country code ("IL") then i get country code value 972
but I want to do only pass number and get any of the country code value.

I don't want to  pass  "IL". And i just want to do it only for received call by mobile. 
Is it possible or not? If possible than reply fast thanks in advance.

```
String number = "+972579481112";
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
   PhoneNumber pNumber = phoneUtil.parse(number, "IL");
        Log.v("Number ",pNumber.getCountryCode());
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My received call like below:
+972579481112

972579481112

+0579481112

0579481112

It is My code  with core java file and add libphonenumber jar

public class Hello {

```
static String[] countrycode = { "AF", "AL", "DZ", "AD", "AO", "AQ", "AR",
        "AM", "AW", "AU", "AT", "AZ", "BH", "BD", "BY", "BE", "BZ", "BJ",
        "BT", "BO", "BA", "BW", "BR", "BN", "BG", "BF", "MM", "BI", "KH",
        "CM", "CA", "CV", "CF", "TD", "CL", "CN", "CX", "CC", "CO", "KM",
        "CG", "CD", "CK", "CR", "HR", "CU", "CY", "CZ", "DK", "DJ", "TL",
        "EC", "EG", "SV", "GQ", "ER", "EE", "ET", "FK", "FO", "FJ", "FI",
        "FR", "PF", "GA", "GM", "GE", "DE", "GH", "GI", "GR", "GL", "GT",
        "GN", "GW", "GY", "HT", "HN", "HK", "HU", "IN", "ID", "IR", "IQ",
        "IE", "IM", "IL", "IT", "CI", "JP", "JO", "KZ", "KE", "KI", "KW",
        "KG", "LA", "LV", "LB", "LS", "LR", "LY", "LI", "LT", "LU", "MO",
        "MK", "MG", "MW", "MY", "MV", "ML", "MT", "MH", "MR", "MU", "YT",
        "MX", "FM", "MD", "MC", "MN", "ME", "MA", "MZ", "NA", "NR", "NP",
        "NL", "AN", "NC", "NZ", "NI", "NE", "NG", "NU", "KP", "NO", "OM",
        "PK", "PW", "PA", "PG", "PY", "PE", "PH", "PN", "PL", "PT", "PR",
        "QA", "RO", "RU", "RW", "BL", "WS", "SM", "ST", "SA", "SN", "RS",
        "SC", "SL", "SG", "SK", "SI", "SB", "SO", "ZA", "KR", "ES", "LK",
        "SH", "PM", "SD", "SR", "SZ", "SE", "CH", "SY", "TW", "TJ", "TZ",
        "TH", "TG", "TK", "TO", "TN", "TR", "TM", "TV", "AE", "UG", "GB",
        "UA", "UY", "US", "UZ", "VU", "VA", "VE", "VN", "WF", "YE", "ZM",
        "ZW" };
static String[] countryval = { "93", "355", "213", "376", "244", "672",
        "54", "374", "297", "61", "43", "994", "973", "880", "375", "32",
        "501", "229", "975", "591", "387", "267", "55", "673", "359",
        "226", "95", "257", "855", "237", "1", "238", "236", "235", "56",
        "86", "61", "61", "57", "269", "242", "243", "682", "506", "385",
        "53", "357", "420", "45", "253", "670", "593", "20", "503", "240",
        "291", "372", "251", "500", "298", "679", "358", "33", "689",
        "241", "220", "995", "49", "233", "350", "30", "299", "502", "224",
        "245", "592", "509", "504", "852", "36", "91", "62", "98", "964",
        "353", "44", "972", "39", "225", "81", "962", "7", "254", "686",
        "965", "996", "856", "371", "961", "266", "231", "218", "423",
        "370", "352", "853", "389", "261", "265", "60", "960", "223",
        "356", "692", "222", "230", "262", "52", "691", "373", "377",
        "976", "382", "212", "258", "264", "674", "977", "31", "599",
        "687", "64", "505", "227", "234", "683", "850", "47", "968", "92",
        "680", "507", "675", "595", "51", "63", "870", "48", "351", "1",
        "974", "40", "7", "250", "590", "685", "378", "239", "966", "221",
        "381", "248", "232", "65", "421", "386", "677", "252", "27", "82",
        "34", "94", "290", "508", "249", "597", "268", "46", "41", "963",
        "886", "992", "255", "66", "228", "690", "676", "216", "90", "993",
        "688", "971", "256", "44", "380", "598", "1", "998", "678", "39",
        "58", "84", "681", "967", "260", "263", };

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String numbe = "9408135563";
    for (int i = 0; i < countrycode.length; i++) {
        if (numbe.startsWith("+"+countryval[i])) {
            System.out.println(countrycode[i]);
            PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
            try {
                PhoneNumber pNumber = phoneUtil.parse(numbe, countrycode[i]);
                System.out.println("code  "+pNumber.getCountryCode()+"Number "+pNumber.getNationalNumber());
            } catch (NumberParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(numbe.startsWith(countryval[i])){
            System.out.println(countrycode[i]);
            PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
            try {
                PhoneNumber pNumber = phoneUtil.parse(numbe, countrycode[i]);
                System.out.println("code  "+pNumber.getCountryCode()+"Number "+pNumber.getNationalNumber());
            } catch (NumberParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(numbe.startsWith("0")){
            System.out.println("code  "+numbe.substring(0,1)+"Number "+numbe.substring(1));
        }else if(numbe.startsWith("+0")){
            System.out.println("code  "+numbe.substring(0,2)+"Number "+numbe.substring(2));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: [Refer this API's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimCountryIso%28%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only way I know is you need to have a list of country codes with you and check the codes with the received phone no i.e:

```
phoneNumber.startsWith(countryCode);
```

**EDIT:**

You can follow another approach if the no of digits in the phone number are confirmed.
I mean to say if you know the phone number will always have say 10 digits of mobile number then you can always get the country code by getting the substring from the phone number from index 0 to (length of phone no - 10 ).

Comment: but some times my number has no countrycode and it is start with anothercountry code like 9408135563 and 94 and it is another country code Sri Lanka than how to distinguish. and my number is india

Comment: you have the list of country codes and you check for every country code until it matches with the phone number.

Comment: your number get's split then there must be some other issue, can you share the code?

Comment: please see above my code implementation in core java and digit length is not fixed